# Complete He has nothing to do all day and is suffering from ____ boredom

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, synonyms

Which is the correct sentence:

1. He has nothing to do all day and is suffering from **critical** boredom.
2. He has nothing to do all day and is suffering from **chronic** boredom.
3. He has nothing to do all day and is suffering from **serious** boredom.
4. He has nothing to do all day and is suffering from **terminal** boredom.

Comment: Feels like I'm doing your homework for you. All could be used; some a lot less formally than others.

Comment: would you arrange them in an ascending order from the least formal to the most formal

Comment: They're all very colloquial, except perhaps 3. 'Boredom' is just one of those words you get to have fun with; you can put some really bizarre things in front of it to really emphasise just how bored you are. Terminal boredom, for instance - I'm sure no-one ever actually died of boredom, yet it's a common-enough usage. Note the examples are all actually proper medical terms, applied to something that is not in any way an illness.

Answer (score 1):

> critical

This means "severe" or that the boredom is very intense or strong.

> chronic

This means that it happens every so often.  This is correct if whoever "he" is experiences boredom at regular intervals.  However, we don't have enough information to know that from just this sentence - though it may make the most sense - perhaps throughout the day he's getting bored from time to time.

> serious

In this sentence I would say it means the same as "critical."

In my opinion, if you have to pick one correct answer, you can't pick *critical* or *serious* since both of them mean the same thing.

> terminal

This means that it kills you.  It's mostly heard in a medical context, and might be intended humorously, but a comedic context would really need to be established first.